# How do I split main.js of my Electron application?

Tags: electron

Electron uses main.js as the starting point of application. However, if that file contains all code which handles events of the main process, it is too long and too hard to maintain. Can I split main.js file? and how do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I reached my expectation. Firstly, I imported my module at main.js by using require() method. Secondly, I used ipcMain and ipcRender to create communication channel between main process and render process.

My modules is independent of main.js so I still need to import Electron module normally.

Answer (score 3):

You can split up your code into CommonJS modules which are described at depth in the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html).

Comment: Thank Vadim, I will give a try and respond to you if your suggestion helps me to reach my expectation.

Comment: Hi Vadim. Thank you for your suggestion but it does not help me. Maybe you understand my question incorrectly. I want to split up the code into Electron modules, not NodeJS modules.

Comment: @Linh NodeJS is integrated into Electron, so Electron uses the same module format (CommonJS) as NodeJS.

Comment: I knew that but i couldn't call NodeJS modules from a remote page

Comment: @VadimMacagon, is it possible so that if a function call to main.js fails that it looks in the required modules of main.js to find the function declaration that it was looking for?